# chkconfig not automatically starting mysql

Tags: mysql, service, sles, chkconfig

I have mysql set in chkconfig to automatically start when the system reboots:

```
root@myserver:~#chkconfig mysql
mysql  on
```

However, this does not seem to be the case. When the system reboots, I get the following error on my PHP pages:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

If I run `service mysql start`, the PHP pages begin to work (the above error does not appear, and queries return values). Is this an inappropriate configuration on my part? What else do I need to do to get mysql to start correctly after a reboot?

Note: I'm running mysql on a SLES VM.

Comment: Is it able to start at all? Are you getting errors in the mysql logs?

Comment: It starts fine if I run `service mysql start`, but not at boot. My `/var/log/mysqld.log` file only shows from the point I ran `service mysql start`.

Comment: `ps aux |grep mysql`. It there another MySQL daemon running already?

Comment: No mysql process was running until I started it myself.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something went wonky when the init script was installed. I'd recommend the following:

```
chkconfig --del mysql
chkconfig --add mysql
chkconfig mysql on
```

Certainly can't hurt.

Comment: chkconfig mysqld ...

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends upon the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting up MySQL at the correct init level ? the network services should be up before mySQL can be started . 
S

Comment: Are you talking about runlevels? If so, both `network` and `mysql` are set to 2,3, and 5

Answer (score 0):

mysql is the client. If you have installed mysql server before, you can start it with

> service mysqld start

Please check:

> chkconfig mysqld